# Gradle could not find method compile() - v28?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I've been getting an error when syncing Gradle:

```
Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
```

I've found solutions for previous versions but I've been developing for v28, and I'm not even sure if my `compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0"` line is correct. This is for a firebase chat app and I'm following a 2016 tutorial. I did end up installing the support thing from the manager but same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use `compile` in version 4.4 of Gradle and instead reduce it by using `implementation` method

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Comment: This solved it, I also had to increase the `minSdkVersion` at the top of the file to solve following errors.

Comment: Actually, that's wrong. You *can* use it in 3 and up (I've done it myself in 3.0). It depends on the version of Gradle. It's deprecated in Gradle, not in the IDE

Comment: In principle you are right but they are linked together

Answer (score 0):

I have also completed a quite similar tutorial - creating the "Flashchat" app.
I ran into the same problem - apparently they updated the keyword used in the gradle files:

> build.gradle (Module: app) - you will find dependencies at the bottom.
>   There you will be able to add the firebase libary as well as other ones. Example:

```
implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0"
```

Unfortunately, the tutorial from 2016 is outdated so you might find several of those little changes later on. For example creating the firebase database will be a little different because they introduced a Real Time Database. (You can still use the old one for your chat app but you will have to change the ruleset for read and write access.)

For further questions you might run into, I recommend searching for "Flashchat" on GitHub. Many people have followed that tutorial and have uploaded their results. This might solve upcoming questions by just comparing the code and then looking up the documentation to understand what has changed. [Link to GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=flashchat)